# Copy attributes from parent to inner controls in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to make an angular directive, say `<my-directive/>`. The directive should be like:

```
<div>
    <input />
    <button></button>
</div>
```

I would like to copy the attributes I add to my directive to the inner `input` element. So say if I write

```
<my-directive ng-model="ctrl.some" 
              pattern="/.../" 
              placeholder="some placeholder for input" 
              required />
```

these attributes should be copied to the input in my directive. Can I achieve this in a good way? Or should I make my directive on another way?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, if you are creating your own directive, i guess you won't be using the ng-model and other names as it is.

Now, say we create a new directive `my-directive`

In the Directive Definition, we can assign these attributes to variables on the directive `scope` and so they would be visible to the inner controls.

Something like this

```
return {
    scope:{
        model:'=',
        myplaceholder:'='
    },
    link : //process the scope variables here, as required
    ...

    template:'<input ng-model="model" placeholder="{{myplaceholder}}"/> ... '

}
```

something like this (not the exact code), and it should work.

Use it as:

```
<my-directive model="someScopeVar" myplaceholder="someOtherScopeVar">
</my-directive>
```

Note the `{{ }}` around `myplaceholder` in `template`, that is because `placeholder` property expects an interpolated string and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the attributes of the directive in the link function.
In the example below the first input is a text input, the second is a password input. The type of the input is passed from the directive attributes.

To pass ng-model is more complex. You should use the isolate scope.

https://plnkr.co/edit/rxgE7BtVR9mEeqKhwfNn

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controlle="testCtrl">
    <h1>Test directive</h1>
    <test-directive required="true" type="text"></test-directive>
    <test-directive required="true" type="password"></test-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

directive-template.html

```
<div>
  <input />
  <buuton>Button</buuton>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp',[]);

appModule.controller('testCtrl',[]);
appModule.directive('testDirective',function(){
  return {
    templateUrl:'directive-tpl.html',
    link:function(scope,element,attr){
      var inputEl = element.find('input');
      inputEl.attr("required",attr.required);
      inputEl.attr("type",attr.type);
    }
  }
})
```